# Cordova and ajax not found rest service

Tags: android, json, ajax, cordova, rest

Do you know why when you place the application on the mobile device and try to download JSON, jquery mobile (ajax) returns me the error 404, and if the same device in browser (chrome) json response is visible?

Does the application in Cordova can block access to the services of rest?

Cordova: 6.1.0
Android-cordova: 5.1.1
Device: Nexus
Service: GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the whitelist blocks external calls on default

add this plugin, if is not added yet

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

And add this meta tag to your html

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"/>
```

Comment: cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist - works great;)

Comment: grad to hear :) please accept answer or upvote if this helped you ;)